# Shell script while loop not exiting

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, wget

I have a shell script with a while loop which is not exiting out.The `wget` statement will return me `true` or `false`. I need to execute the commends till the value is `true`

```
#!/bin/bash
status="false";
while [ "$status" != true ]
 do
  status=`wget -q -O - http://server`
  echo $status
  echo "Sleeping for 5 sec";
  sleep 5;
done
```

**Output:**

```
false
Sleeping for 5 sec
false
Sleeping for 5 sec
true
Sleeping for 5 sec
true
Sleeping for 5 sec
true
.............
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell for certain, but I suspect the problem is that the response is coming back from the server with a CRLF line terminator (i.e the carriage return character followed by linefeed). When the shell does command substitution on `wget ...`, it trims the ending linefeed, but not the carriage return; as a result, "$status" isn't "true", it's "true\r" (with \r indicating the CR). You can use the `tr` command to strip CRs and avoid confusion:

(EDIT: Apparently there are also stray newlines as well; I added that to tr's kill list, and just in case added some ... clarification ... to the echo command to show any invisibles that sneak through.)

```
#!/bin/bash
status="false";
while [ "$status" != true ]
 do
  status=$(wget -q -O - http://server | tr -d "\r\n")
  echo "'$status'" | cat -v
  echo "Sleeping for 5 sec"
  sleep 5
done
```

(I also removed a couple of redundant semicolons and replaced the backquoted command substitution with `$( ... )` -- it does the same thing, but is much easier to read and avoids some odd syntax glitches with nesting and escapes).

Comment: Thanks..It worked after I combined trimming the `\n` as well. I have updated the above solution accordingly.

Comment: I edited your edit siightly -- `tr` can kill more than one character at once.

Answer (score 0):

There are some quoting issues in your script and the way you are starting the sub shell is invalid syntax.

Also you should make sure, that there is no trailing whitespace or other characters:

```
#!/bin/bash
status="false";
# quote the "true"
while [ "$status" != "true" ]
 do
  # use $(...) to start a sub shell
  status=$(wget -q -O - http://server)
  # add >> << to make extra space visible. use quotes
  echo ">>$status<<"
  echo "Sleeping for 5 sec";
  sleep 5;
done
```

Comment: Its giving the output as `>>>se` or `>>>e` . Its skipping the first 3 characters in `false` and `true`